# Can SpannableString be Serializable?

Tags: java, android, serializable, spannablestring

I want post an object with SpannableString by Intent. I let the object implement Serializable, but it will throw

> java.io.NotSerializableException: android.text.SpannableString

So I let SpannableString implement Serializable.

```
private class MySpannableString extends SpannableString implements Serializable{
    public MySpannableString(CharSequence source) {
        super(source);
    }
}
```

But I can't get the object in the next Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation for SpannableString, it does not implement the Serializable interface, hence you got the "java.io.NotSerializableException" exception.

Doc - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html

Your approach to workaround this by extending SpannableString and implementing the Serializable interface will not work. The reason for this being that in order to make a non-serializable Class serializable by extending it, it needs to have an accessible no-argument constructor. The SpannableString class does not have that, the only accessible constructor that is has takes a CharacterSequence as an argument.

As per the documentation for the Serializable interface -

*"To allow subtypes of non-serializable classes to be serialized, the subtype may assume responsibility for saving and restoring the state of the supertype's public, protected, and (if accessible) package fields. The subtype may assume this responsibility only if the class it extends has an accessible no-arg constructor to initialize the class's state. It is an error to declare a class Serializable if this is not the case. The error will be detected at runtime."*

Doc - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Answer (score 3):

I have tested pass `SpannableString` as `Serializable` but it will throw error in second activity like `Can not cast Serializable to SpannableString, null value will return as default`. So I think it may impossible.

However we can pass `SpannableString` by simple way below

First Activity

```
SpannableString text == ...;
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY", text);
startActivity(intent);
```

Second Activity

```
SpannableString a = (SpannableString). getIntent().getCharSequenceExtra("KEY");
//we can get value because SpannableString implements CharSequence
```

[DEMO](https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/StackOverFlowDemo/tree/master/ParseSpannableStringViaIntent)

Answer (score 1):

you cannot serialize it directly, but you can make wrapper which will convert spannable to HTML and serialize string.

```
class SpannableWp(var spannable: SpannableString? = null) : Serializable {


  @Throws(IOException::class)
  private fun writeObject(stream: ObjectOutputStream) {
    stream.writeObject(spannable?.toHtml())
  }

  @Throws(IOException::class, ClassNotFoundException::class)
  private fun readObject(stream: ObjectInputStream) {
    val html = stream.readObject() as String
    spannable = SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(html))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I combined *@Yarh* and *@kotoMJ* answers to keep the serialized value in minimum size by parceling it:

```
class SerializedSpannableString(internal var value: SpannableString) : Serializable {

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun writeObject(stream: ObjectOutputStream) {
        val parcel = Parcel.obtain()
        TextUtils.writeToParcel(value, parcel, 0)
        stream.writeObject(parcel.marshall())
        parcel.recycle()
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class, ClassNotFoundException::class)
    private fun readObject(stream: ObjectInputStream) {
        val byteArray: ByteArray = stream.readObject() as ByteArray
        val parcel = Parcel.obtain()
        parcel.unmarshall(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size)
        parcel.setDataPosition(0)
        value = TextUtils.CHAR_SEQUENCE_CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel) as SpannableString
        parcel.recycle()
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as SerializedSpannableString

        val thisSpans = value.getSpans(0, value.length, Any::class.java)
        val otherSpans = other.value.getSpans(0, other.value.length, Any::class.java)
        if (thisSpans.size != otherSpans.size) return false
        return thisSpans.asSequence().zip(otherSpans.asSequence()).all { (thisSpan, otherSpan) ->
            value.getSpanStart(thisSpan) == other.value.getSpanStart(otherSpan) &&
                value.getSpanEnd(thisSpan) == other.value.getSpanEnd(otherSpan) &&
                value.getSpanFlags(thisSpan) == other.value.getSpanFlags(otherSpan)
        }
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var hash = value.toString().hashCode()
        val spanCount = value.length
        hash = hash * 31 + spanCount
        value.getSpans(0, value.length, Any::class.java).forEach { span ->
            hash = hash * 31 + value.getSpanStart(span)
            hash = hash * 31 + value.getSpanEnd(span)
            hash = hash * 31 + value.getSpanFlags(span)
        }
        return hash
    }
}
```

`equals` and `hashCode` implementation come from `SpannableStringInternal`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not direct response to your question. But I was solving similar problem (to pass SpannableString through via safeargs when using navigation components) and there is a trick how to make parcelable wrapper for it:

```
@Keep
class ParcelableSpanned2(
    val spannableString: SpannableString?
) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(parcel.readSpannableString())

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeSpannableString(spannableString, flags)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableSpanned2> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): ParcelableSpanned2 {
            return ParcelableSpanned2(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<ParcelableSpanned2?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}

fun Parcel.writeSpannableString(spannableString: SpannableString?, flags: Int) {
    TextUtils.writeToParcel(spannableString, this, flags)
}

fun Parcel.readSpannableString(): SpannableString? {
    return TextUtils.CHAR_SEQUENCE_CREATOR.createFromParcel(this) as SpannableString?
}
```